# Encountered error setting up plugins for Minecraft Nukkitx server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, minecraft

RPI 2B, running Debian/Jessie, with java version 1.8.0_65.

Downloaded latest nukkitx from https://nukkitx.com.

Followed installation instructions at https://github.com/IntellectualCrafters/PlotSquared/wiki/Installation.

Plugins I have installed:

- Plot Squared 18.07.21-aaa7088-2022
- FastAsyncWorldEdit 18.07.21-a00345f-1159-20.4.0
- DbLib 0.2.3

Error I am encountering:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

Stack trace: https://pastebin.com/C3DrUm0Q.

Full server log: https://pastebin.com/2iuvQmbC.

As you can see, it says that PlotSquared has been loaded, but none of the plot commands are available.  It just says unknown command when I type it.  I have tried several different versions of all of the plugins, and a couple previous versions of nukkitx, all have the same problem.  I'm thinking its something about my device, but I'm still pretty new to Linux and am not sure what to try next.  Any suggestions would be amazing!

EDIT: I download the driver from https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc, and added it to the class path when calling the nukkitx jar to start the server.  This didn't fix the problem.  Here is the .sh file to start the nukkit jar:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $USER
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -cp ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar" -jar nukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev` yet?  It seems like sqlite might not be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I knew sqlite3 was already installed, but I ran the command to see what happens.  See Pastbin: https://pastebin.com/cUFnB97h.  What does libsqlite3-dev give me?  Is it the driver or something?  I installed it, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!  For whatever reason, the JbLib sqlite driver apparently wasn't working.  The solution was to remove JbLib (jar and folder) from the plugins folder, change the start.sh file (which I created according to the installation instructions) to use a classpath command instead of a jar command, add the xerial sqlite driver to the class path, and specify the Main Nukkit class to execute, like so:

```
java -classpath nukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar cn.nukkit.Nukkit
```